# Qual a importância do .env no React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Estou desenvolvendo um site em React e me deparei com o arquivo .env e nele consta o seguinte script `NODE_PATH=./src` para qual seria sua importância no React ? Pois o meu server só funcionou quando eu inclui esse arquivo no diretório do projeto. Preciso de uma resposta que seja clara sobre o assunto, respostas sem fundamentos serão sinalizadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo .env é o arquivo onde ficam as variáveis de ambiente do seu aplicativo.

Em algum lugar de sua aplicação ela deve estar usando a variável 'NODE_PATH' e por isso ele não funcionou. Nesse arquivo também podem ser adicionado outras configurações importantes caso precise centraliza-las.

Você pode pegar essas variáveis de ambiente pelo:
process.env.SUA_VARIAVEL

Vamos supor que você queira digitar em apenas 1 lugar o nome da sua aplicação, para não precisar alterar em todos os arquivos que criou. Dai nesse caso você poderia adicionar no seu .env o seguinte:

MY_APP_TITLE=Nome do meu APP

e lá no seu arquivo js você pega esse dado com process.env.MY_APP_TITLE

Comment: No caso seria apenas um arquivo de inicialização das dependências?

Comment: Não, as dependências estão listadas no package.json

Comment: Atualizei a descrição da resposta, veja se ajuda

Comment: Possui alguma fonte para que eu possa ler a doc por completo ?

Comment: não tenho não, tens que procurar algo no pai google